# sometime application crash at the launch time in 3.1.2

Tags: iphone

```
here is the crash log


Date/Time:       2010-08-31 18:16:52.646 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.2 (7D11)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00003ec0 objc_msgSend + 24
1   HybridMobile                    0x00006f3a 0x1000 + 24378
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0003963a -[NSObject release] + 28
3   HybridMobile                    0x0000309c 0x1000 + 8348
4   UIKit                           0x00074640 -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 120
5   UIKit                           0x0006f824 -[UIApplication _sendApplicationSuspend:] + 736
6   UIKit                           0x00056604 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3576
7   UIKit                           0x00055634 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 60
8   UIKit                           0x0005508c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 4528
9   GraphicsServices                0x00005988 PurpleEventCallback + 1044
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00057524 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 2296
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00056c18 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
12  GraphicsServices                0x0000436c GSEventRunModal + 188
13  UIKit                           0x00003c28 -[UIApplication _run] + 552
14  UIKit                           0x00002228 UIApplicationMain + 960
15  HybridMobile                    0x00003044 0x1000 + 8260
16  HybridMobile                    0x00002fe0 0x1000 + 8160

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000014b8 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00004094 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00057002 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 982
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00056c18 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
4   WebCore                         0x000846f0 RunWebThread(void*) + 412
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b7b0 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000014b8 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00004094 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00057002 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 982
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00056c18 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
4   Foundation                      0x0005a998 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 172
5   Foundation                      0x00053ac6 -[NSThread main] + 42
6   Foundation                      0x00001d0e __NSThread__main__ + 852
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b7b0 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000262f0 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000207e2 __CFSocketManager + 342
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b7b0 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00091720 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000334d8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1592
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00032c9c pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   CoreMedia                       0x00005660 WaitOnCondition + 8
4   CoreMedia                       0x0000553c FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 112
5   MediaToolbox                    0x00003bb4 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 76
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b7b0 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00091720 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000334d8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1592
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00032c9c pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   CoreMedia                       0x00005660 WaitOnCondition + 8
4   CoreMedia                       0x0000553c FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 112
5   MediaToolbox                    0x00003bb4 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 76
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b7b0 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000014b8 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00004094 mach_msg + 60
2   MediaToolbox                    0x00009ca0 FigExpressNotificationThread + 60
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002b7b0 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x001c5480    r1: 0x34327ff8      r2: 0x001ce670      r3: 0x00000018
    r4: 0x001c5348    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fffed84
    r8: 0x001ce670    r9: 0x001fc098     r10: 0x00117010     r11: 0x001ce678
    ip: 0x000253a8    sp: 0x2fffed64      lr: 0x00006f41      pc: 0x31ec3ec0
  cpsr: 0x00080010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x24fff +HybridMobile armv6  <be64d2596afd44d68c5a6b12055235cb> /var/mobile/Applications/27BA92E0-2688-4FE3-BE99-7E609322060D/HybridMobile.app/HybridMobile
   0x74000 -    0x75fff  dns.so armv6  <957f94410f77a351749ac39d2b4b4abe> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv6  <c6ca391c0094661f9a5ae82920fb6afb> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30009000 - 0x30018fff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <c8d157a8f679c33626be3ea12ccbac55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x30019000 - 0x3011afff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <48d461b0b7e4c3c34fdd8906e43a9c48> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3011b000 - 0x30122fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <314f79317c7b3f8ccb5715f50a1c32bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x302ae000 - 0x3031bfff  CFNetwork armv6  <0c45ba25308645c6e0e6a0934c8ecc98> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3046e000 - 0x3048cfff  AddressBook armv6  <314d6d5c19d8a41144176a9772aeeb8e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30494000 - 0x3064efff  CoreGraphics armv6  <724ca87c683dfc06a7b8de93ad7529ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x30683000 - 0x30730fff  WebKit armv6  <0c25498f719543dfe237b3d5ad2b41f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3073a000 - 0x307e7fff  ImageIO armv6  <e89e18aafd3192967ec92cced4d9565c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x307e8000 - 0x307f2fff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <976de01a455ee09d192898dc306043e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30879000 - 0x3087bfff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <12376568046badc4c6993e85624671c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x3087c000 - 0x3087efff  ArtworkCache armv6  <6ed4c29dcdbff2213ce8fa156bd65215> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x308b2000 - 0x309aafff  Foundation armv6  <666e9e488f83b9e196aa70a6b44fdc93> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x309ab000 - 0x309dffff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <dabbf79e438842248b8d8f572c3654b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x309e0000 - 0x30a14fff  Security armv6  <9b4c89ffb90e39d912571072fc4571db> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30aa1000 - 0x30b1dfff  AddressBookUI armv6  <c98c165a4d579948ca0e2be68b46a58d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x30b23000 - 0x30b28fff  ITSync armv6  <69bcae4bd9e96753e063524a636273ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30b30000 - 0x30c56fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <b9a8f3b6eff2d3bd2b8bce13e6559dcb> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30c94000 - 0x30d91fff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <b075dbc5464fe7a390977b818b9e20e5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x30d92000 - 0x30e3efff  CoreFoundation armv6  <bb0a4b864e5807d2d0fb3211b9633603> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30e3f000 - 0x30e49fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <d66542fdb9913ce038758d76d3d0c3f0> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x30eca000 - 0x30ed6fff  IAP armv6  <a6a0371a822d3c58e5dffee0e443b980> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x30ee6000 - 0x30f41fff  CoreAudio armv6  <cd08933a4f7fdab879f5a9a2a0ad2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30f50000 - 0x30f50fff  Accelerate armv6  <21e1dc9fad96f0d51afbeb7f7e006aaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30f73000 - 0x30f7ffff  CoreVideo armv6  <5ff949c6e178ed567a3516fec7a336fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30f8e000 - 0x30f94fff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <6fe2483fe67d4fc5c932ae02a64501c2> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30f95000 - 0x30f9efff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <ee6107a837d8ef6fcd012522ba03fa6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x310af000 - 0x310d6fff  AppSupport armv6  <5c2d41e8c22380b938e7a3194adff14e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31119000 - 0x31153fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <c6fff6661b9edb14db12c52525e3bb51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3115f000 - 0x318b2fff  WebCore armv6  <7621be5a489bafd9129ec542ee5faf6a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x318b3000 - 0x31928fff  MediaPlayer armv6  <f22f50ead6cee45bab50c88b63a571ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x31a51000 - 0x31a98fff  CoreMedia armv6  <459a316db9a67b3f336d081196b17001> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31ac4000 - 0x31ae3fff  Bom armv6  <53d3b28e15e1aef824becf93c177c7c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x31bc2000 - 0x31ca9fff  MusicLibrary armv6  <3619add890481e699291fc9eeb08ff16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x31caa000 - 0x31d0bfff  GMM armv6  <0353946f7ed83f41e2fca11040f47a36> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x31d0c000 - 0x31e02fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <0c9d767c5ea2052102d5364b731774a4> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x31e03000 - 0x31e6dfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <3fa3413ae26f5e206c8a2ee46fb04bfb> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x31e6f000 - 0x31ebffff  Celestial armv6  <e84f58845e735b10ed730c12634172dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x31ec0000 - 0x31f63fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <70da12c30a834268531d6fc845833f9b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x31f8f000 - 0x3202dfff  MapKit armv6  <5aed0939e6a77fe3be17b69236f4e16b> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x320e0000 - 0x3210cfff  CoreLocation armv6  <42ac528bf061b83d5f9247f59be52ab2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x32117000 - 0x3211ffff  AccountSettings armv6  <439ef235750de9dd46831e87cc1d47a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3218f000 - 0x32190fff  CoreSurface armv6  <b9adb2b0f4bed29f5256929a4aac6144> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32191000 - 0x321defff  IOKit armv6  <0c1722088423026dbc67adb8a83c4b8b> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x326f5000 - 0x326f5fff  vecLib armv6  <c8a08b45effd5eb35a476a969628e52d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32822000 - 0x32840fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <be380b5054e27754c41ae8a33bae3f57> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x32924000 - 0x3292cfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <6673f222acee5f3a208169712387862a> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x329b0000 - 0x329c7fff  OpenGLES armv6  <0c5c914ead991e607b89d480e4215fe8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32adb000 - 0x32ae6fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <428a3247762594db6424083116f0aa6a> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32ae7000 - 0x32aeafff  MobileInstallation armv6  <c59c1fc98de6207301cac06aba5f6ad5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32aeb000 - 0x32aecfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <410c46b0db15595f49443de4b0f96bc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32ba0000 - 0x32c4afff  QuartzCore armv6  <ed15a92103e0e93ff9be1ae6422945d5> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32c4b000 - 0x32c57fff  DataAccessExpress armv6  <efb2c271aa7f5672badf415b2bdc3836> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32c58000 - 0x32c92fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <cf9cc6079374718dce29cba9de48b993> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32ca6000 - 0x32cb6fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <050c16b1a6ea7e4e3c80556a2f9c746e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32cb9000 - 0x32cf7fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <457298c79adc8623fa6ad998f871cd5f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32d65000 - 0x32da3fff  CoreText armv6  <d2f43e4a532b83e42561da6f05376b7b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32edd000 - 0x32f00fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <e14d5666f3f164e734735a718c710dd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32fc8000 - 0x3311cfff  AudioToolbox armv6  <449419ad6f59bbfef367d329152d8466> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x332e3000 - 0x332eefff  GraphicsServices armv6  <c3aca9de10fd0878505c53bef91702ab> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33341000 - 0x3339bfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <d0b78bf167d303cb11c7351784af7be9> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x333c9000 - 0x333cdfff  IOSurface armv6  <5eb19b9643e17c51321283ba4a598d22> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x333fa000 - 0x33408fff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <fe7af855ed11fa43582ae7320ea4b679> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x33424000 - 0x33461fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <50e793fc4b4de6b598be29d591a31f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33462000 - 0x33578fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <0a04b31799af43bec335c461e1ba1f8d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x33579000 - 0x3357ffff  MBX2D armv6  <ab6868f9679e912165063f2229b26b64> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x335aa000 - 0x3439bfff  UIKit armv6  <02702efa29385ec77b4fad6771ea9fea> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

looking for suggation?........

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information than a stack trace. Show code for the line that crashes. State what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1- Your code may access a nil object**

The exception address 0x00000000 is a good hint.
Please check your code and add nil verification blocks.

**2- Your code may access an invalid selector**

The code may call a mistyped method or may call a method that is available in iOS 3.2 and later but not in 3.1.2.

Read the console window and note what selector access caused the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Then place your code inside a respondsToSelector() conditional block.

Good luck Pawan Mangal!

Comment: could NULL cause the problem???

in my flow i am calling the splash image manually(simple 320*480 image with duration) then calling the view
in Splash Image view i am notifying App delegate using perform selector
here is my code
if(NULL != mTarget)
 { 
  [mTarget performSelectorOnMainThread: mSelector 
          withObject:nil
          waitUntilDone:NO];
 }